# Runtime vertex generation

Tags: algorithm, procedural-generation

Is it possible to create an infinite world, where the world is generated using an algorithms? Does XNA support vertex loading during runtime?

Comment: I don't see why this was tagged xna, you asking about algorithms and not xna-specific implementation.

Comment: I don't think this make sense as a language/framework independent question ...

Comment: Yes it does, since I’m asking if XNA framework support dynamic vertex loading.

Comment: Your question as stated is not related to XNA

Comment: Please read updated question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three questions can be answered with "yes":

1. **Infinite World**: You can simulate an infinite world by generating only the currently "visible" world objects. This technique is used even for finite but relatively huge worlds (like in WoW, GTA etc.).
2. **Generated World**: Dependent on the given requirements, you may have to ensure that individual parts of the (apparently) finite world are always generated the same way resulting in identical object/vertex constellations. But, maybe not: Worlds "exist" that are not always identical in same places, like in "Die unendliche Geschichte" by Michael Ende.
3. **Vertex Generation**: Yes, they can! And they *are* quite often generated during runtime even for "small worlds" or just single model animations as some animation techniques are based on dynamic vertex generation during runtime for every single frame.